# Calculation of values for confidence bands

Tags: sas

I need actual values for the confidence bands for regression lines generated by SAS during PROC REG. SAS does this automatically when plotting, but I need to know the actual values of the range (knowing this for just some sampled x's would be sufficient.) How can I get SAS to report these values?

Comment: Show the code you're using to plot the graph please. Also, include anything else you've tried or research you've looked into so far.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `output out=` option and specify the `lcl=` and `ucl=` options. This will output variables for lower and upper confidence limits, respectively. The code below outputs a dataset named `predicted` containing predicted values as `pred`, lower confidence limits as `lower`, and upper confidence limits as `upper`.

```
proc reg data=sashelp.cars;
    model msrp=horsepower;
    output out=predicted p=pred lcl=lower ucl=upper;
run;
```